# What else can be moved to my .config director?

Tags: python, bash, vim, ssh, config

I recently installed NeoVim, and loved how its configuration files go in `~/.config/nvim/`. Then while studying Git in more depth, I discovered that its configuration files can be stored in `~/.config/git/`.

There are few other configuration files in my home folder that I'd love to move into `~/.config`:

- `.bash_history` and `.bash_profile`
- `.python_history` and `.pythonstartup`
- `.ssh/`
- `.vim/` and `.viminfo`

I've googled around, but haven't found any information about whether Bash, Python, etc., support moving these config files. Is it possible and how do I do so? I'd love to keep the home directory cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no universal answer for what can be put into `~/.config`**

The [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) defines several environment variables (each should point to a directory used for a specific purpose), and also a number of fallbacks in case such a variable is not set. One of these variables is `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, and its fallback is `~/.config`. So *if* a program is designed to be compliant with the spec, it should read your config files from its subfolder from this directory.

*Whether or not a program uses `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is entirely up to its developers*, it is not safe to assume that if you put a config file into `~/.config`'s subfolder, it will have any effect.

As to the particular programs you mention:

- Bash doesn't seem to support this.
- Python: [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/appendix.html) mentions `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable, which indicates that this particular file doesn't go into `~/.config`. Of course, you can put it there anyway and point `PYTHONSTARTUP` to it, and it should work.
- `ssh`: it doesn't seem to conform to the spec, either.
- `nvim`: if you're using Neovim, there's no need to use `~/.vim`, you can put files from there into `~/.config/nvim/` (in fact, `:help configuration` says you *should*). Likewise, you don't have to use `~/.viminfo` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use symbolic links to move anything you want there. For example,

```
mv .bash_profile ~/.config/bash/profile
ln -s ~/.config/bash/profile .bash_profile
```

This works for directories as well

```
ln -s ~/.config/vim .vim
```

(although for security reasons I'm not sure `ssh` will honor a symlink for `~/.ssh`; you can try, though.)

Files like `.bash_history` are configurable to begin with. Add

```
HISTFILE=~/.config/bash/history
```

to use a file other than the default `~/.bash_history`.

Comment: I appreciate the tip, but the symlinks wouldn't help me clean up the home folder. But now I know at least one file, `.bash_history`, that I can move out of `~`. :)

Comment: Why do you really need to clean it up? They all begin with a dot for a reason; regular tools  (`ls`, glob expansion, etc) will ignore them unless you are very specific about including them.

Comment: It's not a need, just like the idea of all the configuration files being consolidated to a single, non-home folder, location.

Comment: And they will be, for purposes of managing them. The symlinks are just required so that the tools themselves can still access them.

Comment: You should probably put `.bash_history` in `XDG_CACHE_HOME` instead, which defaults to `~/.cache`.